# How to calculate a number with greatest number in array?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array of value

```
if(isset($wholeprices) && !empty($wholeprices)){
            foreach($wholeprices as $wholeprice){
              $get_wholeUnits[] = $wholeprice->Units;
              $get_wholePrices[] = $wholeprice->UnitsPrice;
            }
```

this $get_wholeUnits[] has values such as the following

```
array(
    0=>200,
    1=>150
);
```

this $get_wholePrices[] has values such as the following

```
array(
    0=>50,
    1>70
);

for($get_whol_price=0;$get_whol_price<count($get_wholeUnits);$get_whol_price++){
    if(350 >= $get_wholeUnits[$get_whol_price]){
        $wholesale_price_Set = $get_wholeUnits[$get_whol_price];
        $gross_price = 350 * $get_wholePrices[$get_whol_price];
    }
}
```

Now I have a number 350, I want it to be calculated only with 200 as 200 closest to 350. But if I have number as 190 , than it should calculate with 150 , as it is closest.

Since my code (for 350) has 200 at the first index, and the first if condition to true, it will result me the value, but at the same time, at the second index, again the if condition executes.

I just want  a simple behavior that, whatever the number is, it should identify the closest number irrespective of the index they fall in.

Comment: I dont get what you want, more explain needed

Comment: Is $get_wholeUnits sorted desc?

Answer (score 1):

You have to process the whole array in order to find the closest value.

You need to do something like this

```
$valueToCompare = 300;

$arrayOfvalues = [/*Some different values here*/];

$closestValue = arrayOfvalues[0]; 

for($i=1; $i<count($arrayOfvalues);$i++){
    if(abs($valueToCompare - $closestValue) > abs($valueToCompare - $arrayOfvalues[$i]))
       $closestValue = $arrayOfvalues[$i];
}
```

At last, you will have the nearest value from the array inside the `$closestValue` variable.

Comment: He didnt ask for closest since "Now I have a number 350, I want it to be calculated only with 200 as 200 closest to 350. But if I have number as 190 , than it should calculate with 150 , as it is closest." 150 was the closest for 190...,, and this one gets the closests above or below, not sense at all.

Comment: yes...this is what I wanted... @hamboy75. thank you for understanding the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if i get what you are asking but if i'm not wrong this would work.

```
for($get_whol_price=0;$get_whol_price<count($get_wholeUnits);$get_whol_price++){
            if(350 >= $get_wholeUnits[$get_whol_price]){
               $wholesale_price_Set = $get_wholeUnits[$get_whol_price];
                $gross_price = 350 * $get_wholePrices[$get_whol_price];
                break; //This will exit from for loop since you have the value that you wants.
                }
              }
          }
```